# Ipython3 and Ipython2 conflict

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, jupyter-notebook

On Ubuntu 15.04, I had ipython2 installed correctly and working with notebook, under the condition that I added "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" to the PYTHONPATH.

Now, I installed python3 and ipython3. `ipython3 notebook` works perfectly (provided I remove the above reference from the pythonpath). But `ipython2 notebook` returns

```
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
```

regardless of the PYTHONPATH.

I have python2 and python3 installed in /usr/bin/ and ipython2 and ipython3 installed in /usr/local/bin. The ipythons were installed with pip and pip3.

Now, if I do install `ipython-notebook`, it installs (I think) another ipython in /usr/bin, which also doesn't work.

This is a bit confusing, in other words I have a mess of python distributions.
Next time I should use anaconda, I know. But at the moment I would like to stick to this. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 5):

It is rare that you should set PYTHONPATH at all except for advanced use cases, and you should never set PYTHONPATH to a standard directory that's already on sys.path for one version of Python. The only thing that can do is break Python, especially versions other than the one for which that directory is already used.

How are you installing `ipython-notebook`?

To install the notebook with pip, do:

```
pip3 install notebook
jupyter notebook
```

Take note of the paths where that command has installed files. It will likely be in `/usr/local`.

If you are getting a different version of IPython than you expect, then there could be an `easy-install.pth` messing up your import path. A common problem caused by old and broken `setuptools`. You can test this with:

```
python3 -c 'import IPython; print(IPython.__file__)'
```

and/or

```
python3 -m site # shows your sys.path
```

If you see lines starting with `/usr/lib` in `usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/easy-install.pth`, remove them, they can cause the wrong versions of packages to be imported.

Often, the easiest way to be sure is to remove all versions of a package and start again. You can try `pip uninstall ipython`, and keep repeating until it says there's no version installed. You may also have installed IPython with `apt-get`, in which case you can remove it with `apt-get remove ipython`. Once you are confident that there is no IPython on your system, you can install again with

```
python2 -m pip install ipython
python3 -m pip install ipython
```

(if you want it for both Legacy Python and Python 3)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, let us forget about the PYTHONPATH, I removed the addition. As I said, ipython3 notebook works. Now I removed the apt-installed ipython, and ipython2 notebook gives me the error "ImportError: The IPython Notebook requires tornado >= 4.0, but you have 3.2". However, pip2 refuses to upgrade tornado because "Found existing installation: tornado 3.2
    Not uninstalling tornado at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS"

Comment: UPDATE I solved the tornado issue by removing a conflicting apt-get-installed version of tornado. Now both ipython2 and 3 are working. Thanks for your contribution.